# Bayesian Inference with dropout, validation set

Tags: python, validation, keras

I have implemented the Bayesian SegNet using Keras ([1](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9412)). To do so, I used the following custom loss function, which performs Bayesian inference for validation loss:

```
def custom_loss_Bayesian(y_true, y_pred):

    train_loss = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)                    

    output_list = []
    for i in range(n_MoteCarlo_Samples):                                       
        output_list.append(K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred))

    Monty_sample_bin = K.stack(output_list,axis=0)  
    val_loss_Bayesian=K.mean(Monty_sample_bin,axis=0)

    return K.in_train_phase(train_loss, val_loss_Bayesian)
```

It works fine, but this approach has a big problem. By increasing the number of Monte Carlo samples, the training process takes a lot longer. This is probably due to the fact that the loop for validation loss is calculated for each training batch, but it is not used anywhere. I only need `val_loss_Bayesian` after the end of each epoch. Is there a smarter way to do this? Please note, that I want to use `ModelCheckpoint` to save the set of weights with the lowest `val_loss_Bayesian`. I tried to implement the solution by lovecambi as in [2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3155), such that `n_MonteCarlo_Samples` is selected based on batch number, but it did not work. It appears that when you compile a model, the properties inside the loss function cannot be changed. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in [1](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10426), it seems that Keras calculates the validation loss for each batch at the same time as the training loss. However, during the training process, only a running average is constantly being reported in the log for training. Therefore, the code snippet given above is doing its job as it is supposed to. It is taking log because validation loss is being calculated for each mini-batch. If I need Bayesian inference monitored in each epoch, I have to pay the computational price.